# Using the DDMS to validate an application. Android

Tags: ddms

I have been asked to prove that an SMS messaging application works properly by using the DDMS. I know it works because I've already tested it using two AVMs. I sent the message from the first AVM (5554) to the second one (5556) and it worked perfectly. I don't know how I can show this on the DDMS though. Any links to tutorials? Or maybe someone can give me an idea. I've tried debugging it but I don't see how it proves the app is working (ie: sends the message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx). It's a tutorial outlining how you use the DDMS to test different functions e.g. call, sms etc.